# Solr doesn't find all chinese sign

Tags: solr, cjk

I want to use Solr for a page in chinese. It works fine, but i can't find some of the chars.

I use the SmartChineseSentenceTokenizerFactory in my schema.xml like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.SmartChineseSentenceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SmartChineseWordTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>

    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.SmartChineseSentenceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SmartChineseWordTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I've tried the CJKTokenizerFactory also, the result was even worse.
On an example page i've got the following text (a copy from wikipedia-china)

就必須參加 國中教育會考

It's indexed in Solr and i can search for all sign except 教

This char means something like: teach, instruct, teaching, religion - so it's a normal word.

That's just one example in which single chars can not be found.

Comment: note from the solr wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_Korean): "Be sure to use PositionFilter at query-time (only) as these languages do not use spaces between words." Are you doing this already?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what this note mean. I've the PositionFilterFactory only in the index-analyzer and query-analyzer. I've deleted the Position filter in the index-analyzer now, but this has no effect

Comment: this says that you should have <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" /> at the query-analyzer side. Does not say it should be on the index side. The best bet after changing schema is to reindex everything.

Comment: ok, my last change should solve this. I've reindexed the core. The problem is still the same.

Comment: I have tried using the <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/> For some reason the following two words get combined into one 教育. Does this make any sense in Chinese?

Comment: All i found out is what google translator tells me:
教 means "Teach"
育 means "Educate"
教育 means "Education" - chinese is strange...

Comment: yes, so it means the tokenization is correct?

Comment: i dont't think so, but i'm not that familiar with chinese. I thought when there is a meaning of a single sign, i could search for it.

Comment: you can try slicing the token stream with http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory NOTE: I haven't tried it with chinese.

Comment: sounds like a possible solution. I'm a little bit afraid, that i misunderstood this language and this slicing only makes it worse.
I'll try this solution, thanks for your help. I hope someone with deep knowledge of the chinese language can clear up this sometime :)

Comment: sure, no problem. Hope you can share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, but I believe it's because smart Chinese uses a dictionary that looks for cognates instead of single characters. I can also search for 教育 or 教授 without a problem but then 教 produces nothing. So I have two searches on our site, one uses solr and the other is a simple search against the text, and then I just give users directions on the site how each search works.

What was your ultimate solution?